# How do I figure out what version of Python has been wrapped up with my exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe, py2exe

Basically, I have an application which was written in Python and wrapped up with py2exe to generate .exe. The application currently runs on a pc which doesn't have Python installed. As can be seen from the image there's a python27.dll so this tells me that the application was wrapped up with version 2.7.

[image]

However I would like to know the full Python version used i.e the value of x in 2.7.x. My end goal is to determine whether or not the version is earlier than 2.7.12

EN: Preferably I would like to check this on the PC which is running the application as is.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you execute additional Python commands with that exe? Then you can run `import sys; print sys.version_info`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How would I go about running additional commands from the exe? When I run revision.exe it prints out the revision history of the application and exits. When I run Run250.exe it launches some data logging threads.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with py2exe; perhaps there is a 'console mode' or some such.